# Getting Error "FeatureSwitchNotEnabled" while creating MYSQL through ARM template

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-deployment, azure-rm-template, azure-mysql-database

Getting Error "FeatureSwitchNotEnabled" while creating MYSQL through ARM template
Hi All,

When I create MySQL through ARM Template there are 2 tasks on which I get FeatureSwitchNotEnabled.

1 - Microsoft.DBforMySQL/servers/firewallRules
2 - Microsoft.DBforMySQL/servers/virtualNetworkRules

Do we need to enable any setting to configure these through ARM template. All other 20-30 operations on MYSql completed successfully, except the above 2.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is a snippet:

```
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.DBforMySQL/servers/firewallRules",
        "apiVersion": "2017-12-01",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('DEV-SIT_mysql_name'), '/AllowAllWindowsAzureIps')]",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.DBforMySQL/servers', parameters('DEV-SIT_mysql_name'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "startIpAddress": "0.0.0.0",
            "endIpAddress": "0.0.0.0"
        }
    },
```

Comment: Could you please tell me what you want to do?

Comment: @JimXu - I am trying to create MySQL instance on Azure using ARM template. I exported what was created in our DEV environment and imported into another environment and there are tons of configurations which work fine except the 2 mentioned in the question. For these 2, I get the following error

{ "status":"Failed",
   "error": {
                "code":"FeatureSwitchNotEnabled",
                "message":"Requested feature is not enabled"
               }
 }